# Problems with parsing a .csv file in C, I don't know how to tell my program that a ",,,," is equal to a "\n"

Tags: c, csv, parsing

I'm currently working in tech support for a hosting bussiness, using primarly cPanel. Also, I'm learning how to code (using only C for the moment). The thing is that I'm having trouble parsing a csv file that is created by cPanel, a list with all the information of the domains (Ip, domain name, space avaible in disk, and so forth). Until now, all the files that I succesfully parsed (.txt, .csv, .bin, etc) they all have each new line separeted by a ¿endofline? (\n in C, I don't know how else is called :P), but in this particularly file the end of one line is separeted by a ",,,,", like this:

domain_name, ip, quota,,,,domain_name, ip, quota,,,,domain_name,ip, quota,,,,...

And I don't know how to tell my program that a ",,,," is equal to a "\n". So far I'am only able to read the first domain in the file, but that's the only record that it's returned. The code so far is as follows:

```
void parsear_archivo(ArrayList* lista)
{
    FILE* archivo = abrir_archivo("archivo.csv");
    eDominio* aux;
    char aux_ip[100];
    char aux_nombre_dominio[200];
    char aux_user_name[50];
    char aux_email[100];
    char aux_quota[100];
    char aux_server[100];
    rewind(archivo);
    fscanf(archivo, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", aux_nombre_dominio, aux_ip, aux_email,aux_server);
    while (!feof(archivo))
    {
        aux = constructor();
        fscanf(archivo, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", aux_nombre_dominio, aux_ip, aux_email,aux_server);
        if (aux != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(aux->ip, aux_ip);
            strcpy(aux->quota, aux_quota);
            strcpy(aux->server, aux_server);
            strcpy(aux->email, aux_email);
            strcpy(aux->nombre_dominio, aux_nombre_dominio);
        }
        lista->add(lista, aux);
    }
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

A couple of comments on the code: I'm using an ArrayList to load the file in memory, that was already tested, so I know that it works properly; the functions constructor() and abrir_archivo() are not the problem here (I used them several times in others proyects with no issues -of course, the constructor() function is tailored to fit the specific structure that I'm currently using-).

I don't know much about regular expressions, I know that the ones I'm using right now read in the file until the first "," appears, but  that is just about it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: What would happen if you changed `%[^\n]\n` to `[^,],,,,`?

Comment: All conversions must match at least one character. Only white space in a format string indicates optional white space in the data, and that's only relevant when the conversion specification doesn't skip white space anyway (that would be `%c`, `%[…]` and `%n`; everything else skips leading white space anyway). So, you can't match `,,,,` at the end of a CSV line with conversions like `%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],` (where there might or might not be another `%[^,]` after the fourth matched comma). Somewhere about this point, you realize that neither the `scanf()` family nor `strtok()` is a good idea.